# Curse on Tanjore big temple

Tags: temple

Is there any curse on Tanjore big temple by sage karuvuraar and that's the reason politicians doesn't enter the temple through main entrance?

Answer (score 2):

## Curse on Tanjore big temple by sage karuvuraar.

[**Brihadishwara Temple**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brihadisvara_Temple,_Thanjavur), is a Hindu temple dedicated to Lord Shiva , located in Thanjavur, Tamil Nadu, India.

While searching more about this , I found out that ,there is an ancient  belief that rulers or politicians /Statesmen  who visit this temple through the main entrance  will fall from their post after doing this , by a curse of sage karuvuraar.

Here is the [**Legend of Brihadeeswara**.](http://www.allaboutbharat.org/post/post/thanjavur-temple)

> The temple was constructed over a period of seven years from 1003 to
>   1010AD, and was completed in the 25th year of Rajaraja's reign. It was
>   conceived by Karuvurar, a yogi and siddha, as a tremendously
>   powerfully energy center, and was financed by Raja Raja Chola in the
>   eleventh century. However, according to historical lore, Rajaraja
>   disagreed with Karuvurar over certain aspects of the temple. It isn't
>   quite clear what the disagreement was about but tales tell of how
>   Rajaraja wished that the kumbabhishekam and inauguration of the temple
>   should take place on a certain date, which Karuvurar disagreed with.
>   Whatever the reason, Rajaraja asked the yogi to leave. Karuvurar had
>   to wash his hands off the whole affair. However, he constructed a
>   little hut in the corner of the temple premises and resided there.
>
> When the time came to install the enormous linga into the peetha or
>   avudaiyar, the Chola engineers struggled immensely as the linga
>   wouldn't fit, any which way they tried. Finally, in desperation they
>   approached Karuvurar, who taking his spittoon, spat into it, and
>   handed it to them to place in the peetha before installing the linga.
>   The engineers did as told, and astonishingly, the linga fit. But t was
>   not a happy occasion. Karuvurar's spitting was a symbolic way of
>   saying that the linga was lost. It had become cursed. Since then, many
>   tales tell of the curses that befell the Chola dynasty. Rajaraja
>   himself is said to have committed suicide, though the truth of this is
>   not reflected in any historical sources. Even today, it is said that
>   any ruler who visits the temple will lose his mandate soon!

But this story is likely to be present in puranic accounts like   " **Sthalapuranas** " . According to some sources ,  the "**BhavishyottaraPurana**" contains **"BrihadeeswaraMahatmya"** contain narratives about the sacred  location of the temple, anecdotes related to the building of this temple, stories of the kings  . It is said that  this purana contains many legends related to the construction of the Brihadeeswara temple.

---

[image]